# Is it normal my heroku app postgres database and my local time having distinct datetime?

Tags: database, datetime, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku-postgres

I'm experiencing an issue with a rails app deployed to heroku, actually I don't know if it's totally normal or if there's something wrong.

So, I dug a little bit into the web and I found that setting timezone into heroku app with `$ heroku config:add TZ="America/Sao_Paulo"` could help, but it didn't help that much.

Eg.: While a recent created object `created_at` appears like `"2016-10-22 22:04:20"` my local datetime at the moment was `"Sat Oct 22 20:04"`. That's two hours apart.

Answer (score 0):

Rails always stores time in UTC by default. This is to avoid confusion when changing to different time zones. Adding changes to config files, will not reflect while storing data in database.